# How are NSBlock objects created?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

*I will preface this question by stating that what I am about to ask is for educational and possibly debug purposes only.*

How are block objects created internally in the Objective C runtime?

I see the hierarchy of classes that all represent various block types, and the highest superclass in the hierarchy, below `NSObject`, is `NSBlock`. Dumping for class data shows that it implements the `+ alloc`, `+ allocWithZone:`, `+ copy` and `+ copyWithZone:` methods. None of the other block subclasses implement these class methods, which leads me to believe, perhaps mistakenly, that `NSBlock` is responsible for block handling.

But these methods seem not to be called at any point during a block's life time. I exchanged implementations with my own and put a breakpoint in each, but they never get called. Doing similar exercise with `NSObject`'s implementations gives me exactly what I want.

So I assume blocks are implemented in a different manner? Anyone can shed a light on how this implementation works? Even if I cannot hook into the allocation and copying of blocks, I would like to understand the internal implementation.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use `[NSBlock alloc]` to create a block, thats why they are not called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## tl;dr

The compiler directly translates block literals into structs and functions. That's why you don't see an `alloc` call.

---

## discussion

While blocks are full-fledged Objective-C objects, this fact is seldom exposed in their use, making them quite funny beasts.

One first quirk is that blocks are generally created on the stack (unless they are global blocks, i.e. blocks with no reference to the surrounding context) and then moved on the heap only if needed. To this day, they are the only Objective-C objects that can be allocated on the stack.

Probably due to this weirdness in their allocation, the language designers decided to allow block creation exclusively through block literals (i.e. using the `^` operator).
In this way the compiler is in complete control of block allocation.

As explained in the [clang specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#blocks-as-objects), the compiler will automatically generate two structs and at least one function for each block literal it encounters:

- a block literal struct
- a block descriptor struct
- a block invoke function

For instance for the literal

```
^ { printf("hello world\n"); }
```

on a 32-bit system the compiler will produce the following

```
struct __block_literal_1 {
    void *isa;
    int flags;
    int reserved;
    void (*invoke)(struct __block_literal_1 *);
    struct __block_descriptor_1 *descriptor;
};

void __block_invoke_1(struct __block_literal_1 *_block) {
    printf("hello world\n");
}

static struct __block_descriptor_1 {
    unsigned long int reserved;
    unsigned long int Block_size;
} __block_descriptor_1 = { 0, sizeof(struct __block_literal_1), __block_invoke_1 };
```

(by the way, that block qualifies as global block, so it will be created at a fixed location in memory)

So blocks are Objective-C objects, but in a low-level fashion: they are just structs with an `isa` pointer. Although from a formal point of view they are instances of a concrete subclass of `NSBlock`, the Objective-C API is never used for allocation, so that's why you don't see an `alloc` call: literals are directly translated into structs by the compiler.

Comment: I don't believe global blocks are created on the heap; the document you link to clearly shows (right after the code snippet you pulled out) that the block will be a stack block. (Which makes sense; why would you put it on the heap if it has no runtime data?) Also, I don't believe it is true they are the only objective-c objects that are stack allocated; under 64-bit ABIs, the whole object may be embedded in your pointer; so they could be even just register-allocated. :)

Comment: @JesseRusak global blocks are pretty much like `NSString` literals. They live in a fixed location as they are constant objects. Creating them on the stack would require allocating them every time the stack frame is built, but this is optimized away thanks to the fact they don't hold any reference to the surrounding context. This is well explained here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Comment: @JesseRusak concerning the 64-bit concern, while it *could* be done, I don't have any reference stating that it's actually been done. As far as my knowledge goes all Objective-C objects live exclusively on the heap, with the notable exceptions of blocks. Of course I would love to be proven wrong if you have extra references you can provide :)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thx! This is what I feared from. I started a little experiment to help me debug, where I would snapshot the call stack symbols for each object allocation. Fun stuff. Works great too, even creates a history for copied objects. Except for darn blocks.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I still object to your statement the "block qualifies as global block, so it will be created on the heap" -- global blocks are not heap allocated; the fixed location they live in is not on the heap.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella As for 64-bit tagged object pointers, you can find references to it [in this post](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in), though I'm sure there's something more authoritative somewhere..

Comment: @JesseRusak thanks for the reference, but I still defend my sentence: you cannot allocate Objective-C objects on the stack. Tagged pointers are an internal platform-specific optimization, so I feel like we are touching two very different levels of abstraction here.

Comment: The proper emphasis is *you* cannot allocate Objective-C objects outside the heap. The compiler and runtime use global storage and stack storage in a handful of places, such as block objects, constant string objects, and tagged pointer objects. But *you* cannot do the same without exotic tricks.

Comment: @GregParker Out of interest, could you please share some info on the exotic tricks? Thanks

Comment: The tricks typically start with (1) allocate memory with alloca(), (2) use object_setClass() to set an isa in that memory. Additional complications are required if any code calls -retain on that object.

Answer (score 7):

As described in other answers, block objects are created directly in global storage (by the compiler) or on the stack (by the compiled code). They aren't initially created on the heap.

Block objects are similar to bridged CoreFoundation objects: the Objective-C interface is a cover for an underlying C interface. A block object's `-copyWithZone:` method calls the `_Block_copy()` function, but some code calls `_Block_copy()` directly. That means a breakpoint on `-copyWithZone:` won't catch all of the copies.

(Yes, you can use block objects in plain C code. There's a `qsort_b()` function and an `atexit_b()` function and, uh, that might be it.)

Comment: Hi, so global storage does not equal to stack?

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are basically compiler magic. Unlike normal objects, they are actually allocated directly on the stack — they only get placed on the heap when you copy them.

You can read Clang's [block implementation specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#blocks-as-objects) to get a good idea what goes on behind the scenes. To my understanding, the short version is that a struct type (representing the block and its captured state) and a function (to invoke the block) are defined, and any reference to the block is replaced with a value of the struct type that has its invoke pointer set to the function that was generated and its fields filled in with the appropriate state.